# Firestore Request, check if doc exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling for a while now with this Firestore check.

```
let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

console.log(currentUser.uid);
let docRef = db.collection("StartNumbers").where('UserId', '==', currentUser.uid);
docRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists){
                console.log('document exists')
                chooseMode.style.display = 'grid';
                onlinePopout.style.display = 'none';
                console.log('user is logged in');   
            } else { 
                console.log('no such document');
                nameOuter.style.display = 'grid';
            }
        });    
}).catch ((err) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", err)
})
```

If doc exists, everything works fine. If there is no such document nothing happens, no error message, no console.log...

Can you help me finding my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries will returns documents which *exactly match* your condition and that essentially means all the documents returned in a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) exist. Therefore, it's redundant to add that `if (doc.exists)` check in a `forEach` loop.

> If there is no such document, nothing happens.

You should use `.empty` property on the `QuerySnapshot` itself to check if your  query returned any matched documents like this:

```js
let docRef = db.collection("StartNumbers").where('UserId', '==', currentUser.uid);
docRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("NO documents matched the condition")
  } else {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    // proceed with adding HTML elements here
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok, I got that, thank you. I cant figure out a way to check, if a document with this certain userId exists and do something if not. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @JohannesBeier this seems to be correct way. Run the forEach loop as I mentioned in the else statement. Just copy my code and you will see all documents where userId is currentUser Id.